# Postgres concat all

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I need connect all columns (unknown columns) from every rows to one string

I want do sth like this:

```
select concat(*) from table;
```

The problem is that the function concat doesn't take parameter "*"

Anyone can help me?

Example:

Table

```
GID | Name
----------
1   | nameA
2   | nameB
3   | nameC
```

I need on output:

```
1nameA
2nameB
3nameC
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
select rtrim(ltrim(replace(tablename::text, ',', ''), '('), ')') from tablename;
```

Answer (score 12):

I would propose two options. They both work using `table_row to text` technique.

1. Quick and dirty:

   ```
   select r::text from some_table AS r
   ```

   Sample output:

   ```
   (289,310,,2010-09-10,6,0,1,6,0,30514,6,882,8,4,1,7,2,2,3,1,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,,1,51,0,0,0,0,0,1386,1,1,,6,,0,,,010100002082080000B3EA73156DA25C411E85EB61CB155641)
   ```
2. Quick with a possibility to manipulate the data:

   ```
   select translate(string_to_array(r::text, ',')::text, '()', '')::text[] from some_table AS r
   ```

   which returns an actual array of text (`text[]`) on which any array function can be applied :)
   Sample output (note starting and ending parenthesis type):

   ```
   {289,310,"",2010-09-10,6,0,1,6,0,30514,6,882,8,4,1,7,2,2,3,1,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,"",1,51,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1386,1,1,"",6,"",0,"","",010100002082080000B3EA73156DA25C411E85EB61CB155641}
   ```

Using the second approach and `array_to_string(array, delimiter)` function you can concatenate all column textual representations into one string. Just pick a delimiter (e.g. `','`, `'|'` or even `''`). For example using `'|'` you end up with a query:

```
select array_to_string(translate(string_to_array(r::text, ',')::text, '()', '')::text[], '|') from some_table AS r
```

with sample output:

```
289|310||2010-09-10|6|0|1|6|0|30514|6|882|8|4|1|7|2|2|3|1|2|2|2|1|2|2|2||1|51|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|1|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|2|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|1|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|1|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|1386|1|1||6||0|||010100002082080000B3EA73156DA25C411E85EB61CB155641
```

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Try `select concat(gid, user) from foo;`, as in [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/787d6/2).

Comment: I don't know the columns. I want to use this solution in procedure in for statement. So I can't use as parameters names of the columns.